# Is there any wrong in the testcpp code of Cocos2d-X?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have donwload the Cocos2d-X and compile the testcpp. But there is something wrong with it, I locate it and find the following code has something wrong.

```
debugForNormalSprite->drawPoints(positions, 4, 8, Color4F{0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0});
```

after I check the definition of drawPoints function. I change the braces to parentheses and it works. Is the source code wrong or just my compiler wrong? I think the last parameter is just a temporary object to pass the value and am I right? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is called uniform initialization, which was added in C++11 standard. Basically, it is just another way to call a constructor, so

```
Color4F{0.0,1 .0,1.0,1.0}
```

is equivalent to

```
Color4F(0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)
```

Here you can see how it works on a simple example: [ideone.com/heJJuI](https://ideone.com/heJJuI)

As for your compilation problem, it is probably caused by an old compiler, which doesn't support uniform initialization. You can try to compile this example from the Ideone to figure this out (just don't forget to compile it with C++11/14 support).